# Get hard disk size flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know how can I get hard disk free size in flutter desktop app?

I have already try with [disk_space](https://pub.dev/packages/disk_space) package but it's not work with desktop platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this package,
https://pub.dev/packages/size

```
import 'package:size/size.dart';
void main() async{
  await Size.init(); // Initialize plugin
  var x = Size();
  print(x.getAvailableDiskSpace('/home'));  // 800007566 -> int
  print(x.getFreeDiskSpace('/home'));  // 800002566 -> int
  print(x.getDiskCapacity('/home'));  // 4540002566 -> int
  print(await Directory.current.is_empty()); // false -> bool
```

or use this package
https://pub.dev/packages/disks_desktop

See example here: https://pub.dev/packages/disks_desktop/example

Comment: welcome, for more flutter educational videos,
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGXMHY0AzAKWZi3398xtUpL4whvRsXWi

Comment: Size not support MacOs yet. Do you know another package to get it in MacOs ?

Comment: The disks_desktop does not support free or available disk space, and, like Moïse stated, the size package does not support MacOS.